(Spring boot upgrade from 2.7) FetchType.LAZY stack overflow
I upgraded spring boot from 2.7 to 3.1.11 and java from 11 to 21. I have noticed my app behaving differently without any code changes except for jpa syntax and package changes. I am now getting a stack overflow error because of a lazy loading problem that wasn't happening before the upgrade. I am wonder what did they change in the new version that is causing this.
I have tracked down the issue to this:
public interface AuditEntity {
    User getLastModifiedBy();

    @JsonGetter("lastModifiedBy")
    default String getModifyUserName() {
        if (getLastModifiedBy() != null) 
            return getLastModifiedBy().getName();
        return null;
    }
}


public abstract class AbstractAuditable implements AuditEntity {
    @LastModifiedBy
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="LASTMODIFIEDBY_ID")
    protected User lastModifiedBy;

    @JsonIgnore
    public User getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }
}

public class User extends AbstractAuditable {
    @NotNull 
    @Size(max=50)
    private String fname;
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }
}

When I remove fetch = FetchType.LAZY, it works. But I can't remove all the Lazy loading through my app. I need them in someplaces or I will get an out of memory error because it is trying to load too much from the database. Why is lazy loading suddenly failing with this error?
For example, when I do this, I get the error:
User user = service.getUser();
User user2 = user.getLastModifiedBy(); <-- stack overflow on executing this line
user2.getFname()

I am using dependencies
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.11'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java-library'
}
api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
api 'org.springframework:spring-web'
api 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core'
api 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc11:21.13.0.0'
api 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api'
api 'jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api'
api 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.55'
api 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2'

and a few other dependencies...
UPDATE:
I have actually found out that I can trigger the stack overflow by inspecting the User in the debugger in this line
User user = service.getUser();
I guess that inspecting in debugger the user attributes is also triggering the getLastModifiedBy which causes the stack overflow. I initially thought it was after the lastModifiedBy() user was created on this line
User user2 = user.getLastModifiedBy();

that things were ok and the stack overflow didn't start but I found out that it was actually executing in a seperate hibernate thread and was starting to overflow. I had to turn on the sql logging to see that it was trying to load data from the User table over and over on that line. What is interesting is that I can actually get past this line in the execution and get to
user2.getFname();

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at myservice.doFilter(ServletRequestFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.Saml2MetadataFilter.doFilterInternal(Saml2MetadataFilter.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)

Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIMsg.marshalTTCcode(T4CTTIMsg.java:311)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.marshalBindDBA(T4CTTIrxd.java:223)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.marshal(T4CTTIrxd.java:172)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.marshalBinds(T4C8Oall.java:2246)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.marshal(T4C8Oall.java:1406)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:292)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:511)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1009)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.prepareDefineBufferAndExecute(OracleStatement.java:1270)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1148)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLSelect(OracleStatement.java:1660)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1469)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3760)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3935)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1101)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)```


I have found out this works if I set getLastModifiedBy to return null. So thats why I thought its infinite recursion somewhere.... But why wasn't this happening before in spring boot 2.7? I even tried updating the oracle driver.

Please add the full stacktrace. Updating the driver won't solve a thing. I suspect JPA is to blame (or Jackson) due to the field being lazy. By default Jackson will use field access and not property access afaik, so that might influence things as well.

@M.Deinum I have added most of the stack trace. If you notice there are some oracle driver ones at the bottom.... hmmm. Not sure, maybe its not a recursive stack overflow?

The request was for the full one, as that will show where it originates from. As mentioned I suspct the LAZY for loading the relationship and trying to access things outside of proper tx (or something like that). Or are you using @Data with your entities (which is a terrible idea to start with).

@M.Deinum I updated it to have the full stack trace.
We don't use @ Data.

@M.Deinum you are right about the LAZY loading, I removed it and it started to work. But there are places in our app where we need it, how can I use it correctly in the newer spring boot?

There are at leat 3 "hacks" that could conduct to unexpected result: 1.You use a JPA bean in jackson: do you use Hibernate4Module to avoid Lazy to be auto deserialized? 2.Your User is also auditable, meaning there will be an auto-join on User, meaning that if on a new User it also creates a new User instead on find itself in cache, it could recurse, 3.because you also use@LastModifiedBy to auto-fill the User. Your Question is why it did work before, So I can't answer, but if the question was how to make it work: 1. Separate DB and JSON classes,2.add an Id on User 3.Map the User as a String

@pdem it is a problem with version 3.1.11 of springboot. It seems to completely break lazy loading. I upgraded to 3.2.5 (painfully) and it is working now mostly, but I still have testing to do.

Without seeing all your complete source code it is a bit hard to determine the exact issue, but based on the log you show it seems it is Hibernate to blame. SpringBoot 3 uses Hibernate 6 while SpringBoot 2 uses Hibernate 5, and based on Hibernate's Jira I could find other StackOverflowError issues but not exactly yours unfortunately. So the best answer I can give is:

Go through (if you have not done it) the SpringBoot 3.0 migration guide with regards to Hibernate 6.1 available here. There are links to the Hibernate migration, which lists changes and recommendations that may be good to know.
I do not think it is the cause of your issue but Hibernate 6 has deprecated several dialects and recommends using org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect for Oracle see migration guide. It may be worth to check that as well.
It could be useful (if you have not done it) to enable hibernate logs, to try to detect what Hibernate it is doing. For example:

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
# See param binding
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=TRACE
# See transaction information
logging.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa=DEBUG


I know you need to stay in SpringBoot 3.1.11 but just out of curiosity try upgrading your dependency to SpringBoot 3.2 which brings Hibernate 6.3 just to check if the issue may have been solved or at least you get a different behavior.

Unfortunately you are in one of those cases where you need to narrow down the issue. Sorry for not giving a straight answer but if I were in your shows that would be my approach.

I have added the logging. Its just constant doing this over and over. Its supposed to be lazy loaded. Why is it just ignoring it?
Hibernate: select  from USERS u1_0 where u1_0.id=?

I am going to try upgrading to 3.2.5 today. Its a pain because they support less jpa syntax. It seems like the newer hiberante gets, the worst their support is.

Its also logging this.
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [o.h.t.d.JdbcBindingLogging] binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [722]

Any idea @silver_mx? I also updated with some new finding.

What you show does not look especially wrong, but the fact that there is a recursive call that causes the StackOverflow is definitely wrong. Do you have the possibility to attach a log that file includes everything? What I would do is to check the stacktrace and set a breakpoint (in the source code downloaded by the IDE) where I see the recursive call is being made and see if I can see why this is calling itself. Looking at Hibernate's code may not be the easiest to do but it is what I normally do when I have issues in 3rd party open source libraries unfortunately.

I have just upgraded to 3.2.5, going to provide some results here after some tests. It broke my jackson dependency for some reason.

3.2.5 has resolved my stack overflow errors. I think I will choose this answer, but I still have more testing to do to make sure. I hate the magical combination of versions to get something to work. Its like guessing a combo lock.

do you know what version of hibernate is bundled with 3.1.11? We were using org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.2.24.Final with 3.1.11. I got this from our dependency scan. It seems to be bundled with it.

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.11/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions I see the version you mention 6.2.24.Final.

When migrating from spring-boot 2.7 to 3.x you are also migrating spring-security from 5.x to 6.x
The stacktrace indicates an issue on auth filter chain. The fact that it happens for User entity is probably related to auth flow via UserDetailService
you might want to go over spring-security migration docs.
lacking additional info on your security configurations i'll point out this answer, relating to AuthenticationManager config. (shooting in the dark, but it may shed some light on your issue)
please upload your security config, and i'll try it address it specifically

When we get this overflow, we are authenticated at this point. I don't think its a problem with the security migration docs.
Also if I just delete lazy loading above, other places in our app fail with the same error that are still using lazy loading on different Objects.
